# Baseus usb hub doesn't work on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors

I have such a problem.
I have 2 laptops - HP (intel) and RedmiBook pro 14 (AMD).
Also I have 2 usb hub

1. baseus docking station 17 in 1.
2. baseus usb-c hub 11 in 1.

A problem occurs when I try to use external monitors.

There is no problem with extra monitors, using baseus usb-c hub. Ubuntu shows all the monitors I plugged in through usb-c hub and everything works fine.

As for the baseus docking station, monitors don't work. Baseus docking station uses external power delivery to support all the ports in working condition and also an extra power delivery is supported (in case to charge the laptop through the docking station). The problem is that, Ubuntu doesn't recognize any monitor through baseus docking station on both laptops. On Windows monitors are recognized through baseus docking station.

Both laptops have usb-c and support power delivery.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you dock and connect the monitors. Also look at `sudo lshw`. Read `man journalctl lshw sudo`.